# Pattern matching a singleton list, equivalent/erroneous statements

Tags: list, haskell, pattern-matching

For context I am trying to create a simple function that outputs the elements of a list at even numbered locations.

```
>evens [] = []
>evens [x] = x
>evens (x, y, xs) = x : evens xs
```

Why does this throw a type error on compilation?

I change the second line to:

```
>evens [x] = x:[]
```

and everything then works absolutely fine.

learnyouahaskell.com states that in pattern matching, (x:[]) can be rewritten as [x] but why does this fail in my function definition?

Answer (score 2):

`[x] != x`. A list of one element is different from the element itself. You can replace the `x:[]` with `[x]`, but you can't replace `[x]` with `x`! Also, your third equation seems wrong. You say it compiles fine, so it might be a typo, but, to be sure, here's the full definition of `evens`:

```
evens :: [a] -> [a]
evens []  = []
evens [x] = [x] -- x :: a; you can't use an a where you need a [a]!
evens (x:y:xs) = x : evens xs
-- x :: a; xs :: [a]; evens xs :: [a]; (:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
-- x : evens xs :: [a]
```